# Use of "would" to depict uncertain future

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs

Consider the following scenario:

1. A clinical trial that was initiated in Jan 2021 is currently recruiting participants.
2. The estimated enrollment of the trial is 50 participants.
3. It is not always sure that all the participants will be enrolled in a clinical trial – the study can decide to reduce the number of participants during the study.

In that case, if I have to report the trial information in a report, can I use **“the trial would enroll 50 participants”** to depict an uncertain future event? Moreover, will the use of **“the trial is estimated to enroll 50 participants”** depict a higher level of uncertainty than the former?

**Given the option, which one would you prefer to depict a situation with all the uncertainties involved in a setting of technical report writing?**

Comment: The people running the trial will enrol the participants. You could say "It is hoped/planned/estimated that 50 participants will be enrolled for the trial." using _would_ sounds even more uncertain, as though the trial may not go ahead at all.

Comment: I understand that considering we are building a possible hypothetical because we are planning for the future, wherein there might be a slight uncertainty in achieving specific conditions, we can use would instead of definitive will. However, I find it odd to use “would” to show uncertainty in a technical context.

Comment: If I say that the trial to be conducted has to have many levels of certainty to get-go and to structure the sentence in a way that allows that under specific conditions last-minute changes are possible, can I say that using “the trial is estimated to enroll 50 participants” a better option and makes perfect sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The trial would" isn't appropriate because the trial is definitely occurring. "The trial is estimated to enroll 50 participants." sounds reasonable. Other options that you might consider or find useful are:

- The trial is currently scheduled to enroll 50 participants.
- The trial aims to enroll 50 participants.
- The expected enrollment in the trial is 50 participants.
- We anticipate a trial enrollment of 50 participants.
- A trial enrollment of 50 participants is planned.

These are all essentially equivalent.

Comment: I agree with you on this that the use of “would” doesn’t fit the context. What if I meant to say that the enrollment of 50 participants is uncertain; the number can be reduced under a specific condition. Suppose, I intend to mention that the enrollment of 50 participants is uncertain and is subject to change under some conditions.  In that case, will “the trial would enroll 50 participants” make sense? I am getting confused as “would” can also be used for future events that may change under some specific conditions.

Comment: "The trial would enroll 50 participants." means that a trial may not occur, but if it does, it will enroll exactly 50 participants. This doesn't match the scenario here. It sounds like "The trial will enroll up to 50 participants" is the intended meaning. "Up to" can be inserted in any of the sentences above.

Comment: If it is not much to ask, could you show me few examples where "would" is aptly used to show uncertain events in the future in the context of technical writing?

Comment: The term is used rarely in technical writing, probably most often to consider counterfactual scenarios (“If oxygen lost a proton and electron, it would become nitrogen.”) and to ask rhetorical questions (“Would more efficient solar cells benefit small farm operations?”).

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Much appreciated!